# Import multiple Excel files/sheets into SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ms-office, vba

I have about 100 xlsx files, all with 1-7 sheets each. Each file and sheet has the same columns as the table I want to import everything into.

I can use this successfully:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(
  'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
  'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\0.xlsx',
  'SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]'
)
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE( 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Data Source="C:\0.xlsx";
Extended properties=Excel 8.0')...Sheet1$
```

But how can I import multiple sheets from a file?

Comment: union SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE( 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Data Source="C:\0.xlsx";
Extended properties=Excel 8.0')...Sheet2$

Comment: This is probably best done using an SSIS package...

Comment: @twoleggedhorse I expect you will find locking issues with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create linked server for the Excel file
2. Use sp_tables_ex to discover the tables that the provider returns (mostly this should be the worksheet names but it may depend on the provider implementation)

Linked Server

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
    @server = 'ExcelServer1',
    @srvproduct = 'Excel',
    @provider = 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
    @datasrc = 'C:\Test\excel-sql-server.xls',
    @provstr = 'Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;'

EXEC sp_dropserver
    @server = N'ExcelServer1',
    @droplogins='droplogins'
```

Comment: When you are done, it would be nice to know what, if any, speed differences there are.

Comment: Haven't run any tests but seems like the same speeds for both subjectively. About 7 seconds per sheet either way. Also I ended up using 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' as the provider.