# Import data from multiple worksheets into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, excel, csv

Is there a way to import multiple worksheets into same database table using a script? At this moment, I am saving the `.xlsx` files into 2 `.csv` files and loading the data using `BULK INSERT`. These days data is growing (now about 2M) and facing difficulties in saving the files to `.csv`.

I am not preferring import wizard as I want to run a simple stored procedure to complete the process.

Providing sample data here..

Sheet1

```
1   James   Smith   19750101
2   Meggie  Smith   19790122
3   Robert  Smith   20071101
4   Alex    Smith   20040202
5   John     Roberts    20050612
```

Sheet2

```
6   James   Smith   19750101
7   Meggie  Smith   19790122
8   Robert  Smith   20071101
9   Alex    Smith   20040202
10  John     Roberts    20050612

CREATE TABLE CSVTest
(
    ID INT,
    FirstName VARCHAR(40),
    LastName VARCHAR(40),
    BirthDate SMALLDATETIME
);
```

The below script is working for a single sheet as of now.

```
BULK INSERT CSVTest
FROM 'C:\csvtest.csv'
WITH
    (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n');
```

Please be noted, I may not able to install any additional tools, I want to do it in SQL Server.

Thanks for your time..

Comment: You can use [OPENQUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql) and the associated functions to do this. The sheets and file name would need to be the same unless you want to do something dynamically with a sproc (which wouldn't be too hard but that wasn't your question).

Comment: A CSV file is NOT an excel file. So your comment about "is working for a single sheet" is very misleading. The issue has been discussed many times - e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131711/import-multiple-excel-files-sheets-into-sql-table

Comment: Thanks Jacob and SMor for your time..

Comment: @JacobH and @SMor, I did the below things after your comments..  I am not sure how to format the things in comments
`EXEC sp_addlinkedserver    
 @server = 'ExcelServer1',   
 @srvproduct = 'ACE 12.0',    
 @provider = 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',   
 @datasrc = 'C:\Users\venkat\Desktop\Freelancers\Upwork_tasks\Chris Hickey\Allproducts_sheet1.xlsx',  
 @provstr = 'Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;'                                                      
 '
'SELECT * FROM ExcelServer1...[Sheet1$]'

'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(ExcelServer1, 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')`

Comment: `
I am getting this error now

Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "ExcelServer1" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "ExcelServer1".
`

I checked the provider from SSMS and it is available as the one I am using above

Comment: I tried to follow the instructions from the below link, but unable to modify the startup parameter to append -g512. http://visakhm.blogspot.in/2013/12/how-to-solve-microsoftaceoledb120-error.html